# Delphi XE and Unicode

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe

I have a one function that was working in Delphi 6. Now I trying to migrate the old project to Delphi XE8, but this function doesn't work properly.

Please help me.

old function:

```
function ReadString(var P: Pointer): String;
var
  B: Byte;
begin
  B := Byte(P^);
  SetLength(Result, B);
  P := Pointer( Integer(P) + 1);
  Move(P^, Result[1], Integer(B));
  P := Pointer( Integer(P) + B );
end;
```

I try to changed it to uncode, but it doesn't work:

```
function ReadString(var P: Pointer): String;
var
  B: Byte;
  LResult: AnsiString;
begin
  B := Byte(P^);
  SetLength(LResult, B);
  P := Pointer( Integer(P) + 1);
  Move(P^, LResult[1], Integer(B));
  P := Pointer( Integer(P) + B );
  Result := String(LResult);
end
```

The function use in:

GetIntfMetaData(Myobj as IFController, IntfMD, True);

```
    procedure GetIntfMetaData(Info: PTypeInfo; var IntfMD: TIntfMetaData; MethodArrayOpt: TFillMethodArrayOpt);
var
  I, Offset: Integer;
  Methods: Integer;
  BaseRTTIMethods: Integer;
  HasRTTI: Integer;
  PP: PPTypeInfo;
  P: Pointer;
  SelfMethCount: Integer;
  IntfMethod: PIntfMethEntry;
begin
  P := Pointer(Info);
  IntfMD.Info := Info;
  { tkKind }
  ReadByte(P);
  IntfMD.Name := ReadString(P);
   { Interface flags }
  ReadByte(P);
  IntfMD.UnitName := ReadString(P);
  Methods := ReadWord(P);   { # methods }
  HasRTTI := ReadWord(P);   { $FFFF if no RTTI, # methods again if has RTTI }
  if HasRTTI = $FFFF then
    raise EInterfaceRTTIException.CreateFmt(SNoRTTI, [IntfMD.UnitName + '.' + IntfMd.Name]);
  { Save my method count }
  SelfMethCount := Methods;
    Offset := 0;
  { Size array and fill in information }
  SetLength(IntfMD.MDA, Methods);
  FillMethodArray(P, @IntfMD, Offset, SelfMethCount);
end;

procedure FillMethodArray(P: Pointer; IntfMD: PIntfMetaData; Offset, Methods: Integer);
var
  S: Ansistring;
  I, J, K, L: Integer;
  ParamCount: Integer;
  Kind, Flags: Byte;
  ParamInfo: PTypeInfo;
  ParamName: Ansistring;
  IntfMethod: PIntfMethEntry;
  IntfParam: PIntfParamEntry;
begin
  for I := 0 to Methods -1 do
  begin
    IntfMethod := @IntfMD.MDA[Offset];
    IntfMethod.Name := ReadString(P);
    Kind := ReadByte(P);           { tkKind }
    IntfMethod.CC := CCMap[ReadByte(P)];
    ParamCount := ReadByte(P);     { Param count including self }
    IntfMethod.ParamCount := ParamCount - 1;
    IntfMethod.Pos := Offset;
    IntfMethod.HasRTTI := True;

    SetLength(IntfMethod.Params, ParamCount);
    K := 0;
    for J := 0 to ParamCount - 1 do
    begin
      Flags := ReadByte(P);       { Flags }
      ParamName := ReadString(P); { Param name }
      S := ReadString(P);         { Param type name }
      L := ReadLong(P);           { Param Type Info }
      if L <> 0 then
        ParamInfo := PPTypeInfo(L)^
      else
        raise EInterfaceRTTIException.CreateFmt(SNoRTTIParam, [ParamName, IntfMethod.Name, IntfMD.UnitName + '.' + IntfMd.Name]);
      if J = 0 then
        IntfMethod.SelfInfo := ParamInfo
      else
      begin
        IntfParam := @IntfMethod.Params[K];
        IntfParam.Flags := TParamFlags(Flags);
        IntfParam.Name := ParamName;
        IntfParam.Info := ParamInfo;
        Inc(K);
      end;
    end;
    if Kind = Byte(mkFunction) then
    begin
      S := ReadString(P);
      IntfMethod.ResultInfo := PPTypeInfo(ReadLong(P))^;
    end;
    Inc(Offset);
  end;
end;

function ReadByte(var P: Pointer): Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte(P^);
  P := Pointer( Integer(P) + 1);
end;
```

Comment: What is the definition of the structure that P points to? Please give a full example.

Comment: var Info: PTypeInfo;
  P := Pointer(Info);

Comment: Let the compiler calculate the offsets. It will get them right. Don't run this code in an x64 process.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please hemp me with "Let the compiler calculate the offsets"? 
I don't run this code in an x64 process

Comment: You have a pointer to the record. The compiler knows where the fields are. Why are you doing pointer arithmetic? You are getting it wrong. That `var` param is wrong too. You'll have truncation in a 64 bit process. I'd start with a clear statement of what the code is meant to do. And I'd also recommend using the compiler to write the code rather than you doing it. Stop using untyped pointers that way.

Comment: This looks like very convoluted code to retrieve the  `Name` from a pointer to a `TTypeInfo` record.

Comment: I voted to close because the question is not complete. The only way to make progress is for you to understand your code.

Comment: I guess what you are missing is that the output of your function is determined by both its code and its input. You showed the former, but not the latter.

Comment: Regarding your update, why did you throw away the type information? Do you know what the code is trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. I've just started work with that. Please do not vote down because in a result I can not vote for other post that help me

Comment: You don't seem very keen to understand, is my concern. You seem to want a quick fix. Some magic code. A step back is needed.

Comment: No, I very keen to understand. I need to get all procedures and parameters from interface that pass as varibale Info and save the data to other object. I recently started work on the project and I do not yet fully understand how it works

Comment: If you had explained all that and shown all that in the question that would have helped. You should probably be using new RTTI now. If I were you I'd  throw all the code in the question away. It's far too brittle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution that I found in internet and it work(but I do not know if it's proper):

```
function ReadString(var P: Pointer): String;
var
  B: Byte;
{$IFDEF UNICODE}
{$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
  AStr: TBytes;
{$ELSE !NEXTGEN}
  AStr: AnsiString;
{$ENDIF NEXTGEN}
{$ENDIF}
begin
  B := Byte(P^);
{$IFDEF UNICODE}
  SetLength(AStr, B);
  P := Pointer(NativeInt(P)+1);
{$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
  Move(P^, AStr[0], Integer(B));
  Result := Tencoding.UTF8.GetString(AStr);
{$ELSE !NEXTGEN}
  Move(P^, AStr[1], Integer(B));
  Result := UTF8ToString(AStr);
{$ENDIF NEXTGEN}
{$ELSE}
  SetLength(Result, B);
  P := Pointer( NativeInt(P) + 1);
  Move(P^, Result[1], Integer(B));
{$ENDIF}
  P := Pointer( NativeInt(P) + B );
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the name of the type through the [PTypeInfo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.TTypeInfo) structure:

```
function GetName(p: Pointer): String;
begin
  Result := PTypeInfo(P)^.Name;
end;
```

Or better to fully qualify the pointer:

```
function GetName(p: PTypeInfo): String;
begin
  Result := P^.Name;
end;
```

Or use the built in function:
[TypInfo.GetTypeName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.GetTypeName).

---

What David was pointing out in the comments, the `TTypeInfo` record starts with an enum, `Kind`. Next comes the `Name` string. The offset to this field is better left for the compiler to calculate.

---

In your updated question it is clear that you increment the pointer with 1 (ReadByte) before calling the function to get the name. Don't do that.
Do this:

```
IntfMD.Name := GetTypeName(Info);
```

---

Now, use this knowledge to handle the methods of the `TTypeInfo`, which needs an update too.

Comment: I thought this but what I cannot square is the type kind enum in the record.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the OP's code does not match the kind, for sure.

Comment: Thank you for help.  After change I got something like ''leaseLeave'#0#3#1#8#4'Self'#$10'IFController'#$14'ѓL'#0#2#0#2#0#4'Kill'#0#3#1#8#4'Self'#$10'IFController'#$14'ѓL'#0#2'

Comment: @Mega Step 1. Work out what your code is meant to do. Step 2. Tell us.

Comment: Mega, the only plausible explanation is that you are incrementing the Info variable with 1, before calling the function. This would also match the code in your question. Show a complete example.

Comment: Mega, I'm sure I answered your question now. You need to look at how to handle the methods as well. But try do figure that out, and come back with a new question if you get stuck.